# jQuery live filtering, how do I return entire rows when matched?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the jQuery live filter plugin to make an instant search over a entire table. The plugin works fine but it filters by cell and I'd like to search for an entire row (tr) match instead of just a cell.

HTML:

```
<h2 class="sub-header">List of Enabled Alarms</h2>
            <div id="prefetch">
                <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Alarm name search" id="alarm-search">
            </div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="alarm-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Creation Date</th>
              <th>Frequency</th>
              <th>Enabled</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>60</td>
                    <td>Alarm dev test</td>
                    <td>29-12-2015</td>
                    <td>28-12-2015</td>
                    <td>ExactTime</td>
                    <td>Enabled</td>
                    <td><a href="/alarm/load?id=60" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edit</a> <a href="/alarm/delete?id=60" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>Testing email</td>
                    <td>05-01-2016</td>
                    <td>04-01-2016</td>
                    <td>ExactTime</td>
                    <td>Enabled</td>
                    <td><a href="/alarm/load?id=61" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edit</a> <a href="/alarm/delete?id=61" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#alarm-table').liveFilter('#alarm-search', 'tbody tr', {
      filterChildSelector: 'tr'
    });
</script>
```

The result of this code is partial row information. If I write `a` it returns all cells that match but not entire rows as I expected. I'd like to search only by column `name` if possible.

Comment: The [plugin](https://github.com/cheeaun/jquery.livefilter/blob/master/jquery.liveFilter.js) is about 20 lines long (relevant part is 4 lines, rest is just making it a plugin) - just take the useful parts and make it do what you actually want rather than spend any time trying to work out what it is/isn't doing and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [plugin](https://github.com/cheeaun/jquery.livefilter/blob/master/jquery.liveFilter.js) you can pass filter funtion for matching elements. So try below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#alarm-table').liveFilter('#alarm-search', 'tbody tr', {
        filter: function(el, val){
            return $(el).find('td:eq(1)').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or better if you could give any class name to your cell containing alarm name. In that case your html looks like :

```
<h2 class="sub-header">List of Enabled Alarms</h2>
            <div id="prefetch">
                <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Alarm name search" id="alarm-search">
            </div>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="alarm-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Creation Date</th>
              <th>Frequency</th>
              <th>Enabled</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>60</td>
                    <td class="alarmName">Alarm dev test</td>
                    <td>29-12-2015</td>
                    <td>28-12-2015</td>
                    <td>ExactTime</td>
                    <td>Enabled</td>
                    <td><a href="/alarm/load?id=60" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edit</a> <a href="/alarm/delete?id=60" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td class="alarmName">Testing email</td>
                    <td>05-01-2016</td>
                    <td>04-01-2016</td>
                    <td>ExactTime</td>
                    <td>Enabled</td>
                    <td><a href="/alarm/load?id=61" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Edit</a> <a href="/alarm/delete?id=61" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

and use below script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#alarm-table').liveFilter('#alarm-search', 'tbody tr', {
        filter: function(el, val){
            return $(el).find('.alarmName').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome dear. BTW it was my very first answer on stack overflow. Thanks :)